# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (read from address 0xffffffffffffffff)

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, memory, access-violation

I want to know how to interpret `0xffffffffffffffff` (in backtraces)

I know:

1. reading from `0` / `nullptr` is a not valid address.
2. reading from `0x58`, after the object there was deleted, will result in access violation, because I do not own the memory location.

So for `0xffffffffffffffff`, I know / assume:

1. It's a 64 bits pointer
2. Object behind it is probably not deleted
3. `object* obj;` would create pointer of type object* on the stack, value `0` / `nullptr`.
4. `object* obj = new object()` would create object on heap, store pointer to it in `obj`, with a valid address like `000000000BD0ADA0` - needs to be deleted with `delete obj` at some point.
5. `0xffffffffffffffff` is all 1s in binary.

Question: How do I end up with `0xffffffffffffffff`

1. sounds like a underflow or something, why?
2. can this be related to the compiler, or the debugger?
3. why is it `0xffffffffffffffff` ?
4. **How should I interpret this?**

In my specific case, it's like this:

1. `CustomItem* name_item = new CustomItem (i, elems[i]);`
2. Custom Item constructor

`CustomItem (int sort_val, MyObject *obj) : _sort_val (sort_val), _mobj(obj) { }`

3. `model->setItem (i, 0, name_item);`
4. `#0 Qt5Gui public: void cdecl QStandardItemModel::setItem(int,int,class QStandardItem * ptr64) ptr64 +0xd (ip 0x7fee721bcfd fp 0x168470)`

Comment: Pretty hard to give a complete answer without seeing relevant code, can you post it?

Comment: It's probably an uninitialized pointer, but the compiler places an easly distinguishable value so it is easier to debug.

Comment: "uninitialized pointer" - how do I get this? 

`QStandardItemModel* pointer;` is 0

Comment: Syscall that returns an address/token/whatever if successful, or -1, (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?) if failed?

Comment: "object* obj; would create pointer of type object* on the stack, value 0 / nullptr" - FALSE, it gives u an uninitialized pointer, and your compiler probably fills it with 0xffffffffffffffff so u can tell immediately where's the error

Comment: @Sly_TheKing: `object* obj` + `cout << obj << endl` will give me `0`. Do you mean this is not guaranteed?

Comment: The wonky address is generated when the instruction that failed did so because of a mis-aligned address.  SSEx and AVX instructions.  Easy to see when you use the debugger to look at the fault address.

Comment: @KYL3R It is only guaranteed to be a null pointer if `obj` was declared at global scope (or if it's a member variable that is initialized in a constructor.) Elswehere, `object* obj;`  is uninitialized, and not guaranteed to be null

Comment: @nos thanks, it's in local scope. so I should initialize with `object* obj = nullptr` (c++11) and check against `nullptr` after assigning value?

Answer (score 0):

Comments: It's probably an uninitialized pointer.

I found that:

```
Object* obj; // is 0
```

However:

```
Object* obj1; // is 0
Object* obj2 = new Object(); // is 000000000BF6F100 (some valid address)
Object* obj3; // is 000000000BF6F100
```

**Conclusion: `Object* obj;` is not guaranteed to be 0.**

Compiler or Debugger probably replaces uninitialized pointers to `0xffffffffffffffff`. Apparently only in some cases, because I could not reproduce it in a simple example. I'd like to have a link to some c++ specification, compiler specification or maybe visual studio debugger, that proved this.

Comment: "is not guaranteed to be 0" what in the world gave you the idea that it would be guaranteed?

Comment: static variables for example are in fact guaranteed to be auto-zero-initialized.

Comment: And how is that a guarantee for non-static variables?

Comment: It is not. However this is still not a proof why I end up with 0xffffffffffffffff.

Comment: It is an indeterminate value, the standard dictates nothing about it. You should not do that. C++ is about performance, and so it will not do any run-time nulling unless you do that explicitly, otherwise it will be a waste to set it to zero, and then to something else. For static objects it is different, because the layout and data is determined during compile time, and it incurs no additional runtime overhead.